# Regular expressions in VBScript v/s Regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, vbscript, selenium-webdriver, qtp

While doing a feasibility analysis of a GUI application, we are comparing QTP (VBScript) and Selenium (Java) tools. Selenium being a open source tool does have the advantage when it comes to cost. The GUI application under test has dynamic set of web elements whose properties keep changing. Hence, we are using regular expressions to address that issue.

My question is - 
1. Is using Regular expression in QTP (VBScript) any different from using Regular expression in Selenium (Java)?
2. Is there a good open source tool which can be used to create regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

1) In brief not that much see http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html for gotchas which may affect you

2) There's this site regulary used here for regex exemples http://regex101.com/#javascript which can help you write your regex. I have to say I'm unsure you wich a tester or a builder.

I know no good tool to build regexes in the way they don't analyse your text to magically produce a matching regex. If you look for some guidance regex101 is quite clear. There's also somme 'interfaces' listed here (untested from me)

Answer (score 0):

To vbscript from java no difference or minor difference

To java from vbscript différence because java engine is based on pcre (rich syntax) and vbscript is based ecmascript (poor syntax)